# Adding existing Qt Creator project to Git

Tags: git, qt

Qt Creator comes with git functionality if you've got it installed. Trouble is, it seems you can only make a project version-controlled when you create it?
Eclipse, on the other hand, allows to add a project to version control at any time. Another difference is that with Eclipse the repo can be anywhere and is separate from your workspace, but with Qt Creator it looks like the project and the repo are one and the same directory.

So,

1. Is there a way to add an existing project to version control in Qt Creator?
2. When you do this, is there a way to make the directory with the Qt Creator project and the repo directory different and independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a SC system installed, then under to Tools menu you should see it listed. In mine, for example, Git appears as an option. When you select Git, the submenu has an option to Create Repository. When selected it asks you to select the folder for the respository.

You need to install external tools and then configure Qt creator to use those tools. Under Preferences, select Version Control then the Git tab. Make sure that the Git tools are in the Path. Look here for the tools; https://git-scm.com/downloads.

Comment: I have the same problem. I can see the Git menu and I selected "Create Repository" and chose an empty folder. So how can I commit my existing project(s) to that new repository using Qt Creator?

Comment: Under the Git menu, don't you also have options like "local respository" and "remote repository". Under "local repo..."  you should see "Commit,...". Under Remote, you should have Push etc.

Comment: I can see those menu entries. But all menu entries are ghosted, except "Create Repository".

Comment: see my updated answer. you need to install external git tools.

Comment: I have git installed but I don't have git in tool submenu even listed as ghosted - they just don't appear here at all. Where I open option menu I have Git under version control but there isn't actually anything to configure that so I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. When adding a project to GIT, I could create the repository; but then I couldn't add anything to it.

The solution for me turned out to be that when I was choosing the location of git directory I created a subdirectory (.git) first, and then selected It.  That did not work for me, because it created '.git/.git' -- so I removed the directory and created a new repository... selecting the current directory where my project was.  That worked.